# no eth0 and no wired internet connection

Tags: ifconfig, lspci

yesterday all was fine and Dandy until the internet service went out due to a storm. After my isp got their stuff together all my other devices had internet except for my ubuntu desktop. I booted it off and back on. nothing. I checked the output of 'ifconfig -a' and the only interface shown was the loopback. I made sure that my bios settings were correct and couldn't even find the network adapter in 'lspci -v'

If it means anything my motherboard is a 990fxa-ud3 from gigabyte.
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you give me the output of `lspci | awk '/net/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %`?

Comment: I get no output running that line

Comment: Could you try booting from a live media and seeing if your network adapter gets recognized there?

Comment: I did that yesterday and it was unable to find it. I even installed another instance of the os on another hard drive

Comment: You might wanna check your BIOS settings. Maybe it has become disabled for some reason or another. At this point it isn't a Ubuntu issue,  but something hardware related. If changing BIOS settings doesn't help, contact your administrator or hardware vendor.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to manually add the interfaces to `/etc/network/interfaces`. To see what network interfaces your system has detected look at `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. Any interfaces detected will be identified by NAME= Add the interface names to `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
auto eth1   # eth1 is an example name
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Then use `ifup` to bring up the new interface

```
$ sudo ifup eth1
```

Comment: there doesn't appear to be anything in 70-persistent-net.rules

Comment: no file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules